# Android overheating disconnects from OTG

Tags: android, usb-otg, overheating

I'm encountering a very strange problem while developing on **android**. My project is a bit unorthodox, so please bear with me.

I'm developing a game that uses an external controller that's connected to the phone using an OTG cable. All works OK, until the phone's **temperature** crosses a certain threshold, In which case the operating system **shuts down the communication with the OTG** and I'm unable to restart it in any way other then disconnecting the OTG cable, and reconnecting it, which is a process I would really like to avoid.

So my question is does anyone know what part of the operating system is the one performing this action of shutting down the USB input when the device gets overheated, and where can I control\reboot it?

Would very much appreciate your help, as I don't even know where to start looking, just please avoid answers like "just unplug and plug back the otg", or "just make sure your device doesn't overheat"

Much obliged

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a hardware issue. If it's actually implemented in the OS itself, then you should probably look in the kernel code. It's not the standard behavior in all android devices, so you should try using another device.

Comment: I think its an OS problem, because once while debugging and checking the device battery temperature, I saw it was stuck on 25 (I think it was a sensor malfunction), and when the reading was stuck, even though the device reached really high temperatures, the otg didn't disconnect, so I suspect it's an OS thing more then a hardware thing.